# Observer to watch for two separate events, second one being delayed by AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, observer-pattern

I have a data entry screen where the user can type values and use the `+` key to advance to the next field.  At the last field, the user can either press `+` or `enter`.

The `+` key means to continue entering values into a batch; while the `enter` key means to end adding to the batch and immediately proceed to next page IF the sum of the amounts in database equal the batch amount.

*Simplified HTML:*

```
<div><input id="account"></div>
<div><input id="type"></div>
<div><input id="amount"></div>
<div><button class="disabled" disabled>Next Page</button>
```

*Javascript event handlers:*

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // pressing '+' in account field advances cursor to type field
  $('#account').on('keypress',function (e) {
    // '+' key
    if(e.which==43) { 

      // prevent '+' from being entered into input
      e.preventDefault();

      $('#type').focus();
    }
  });

  // same thing for type field
  $('#type').on('keypress',function (e) {
    if(e.which==43) { 
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#amount').focus();
    }
  });

  // last field can accept '+' or 'enter'
  $('#amount').on('keypress',function(e) {
    if(e.which==43 || e.which==13) {
      e.preventDefault();

      addRecord();

      $('#account').focus();

      // This fails because this is executed before addRecord() finishes...

      // if total of amounts added to db == batchTotal
      if(which==13 && buttonIsGreen()) {
        // redirect to next page
      }
    }
  });
});

function addRecord() {
  // perform AJAX 
  var response = $.post( .. parameters .. );
  response.done(function(result) {
    if(result.status=='success') {
      // redraw some tables
      areAmountsEqual();
    }
  }); 
}

function areAmountsEqual() {
  // perform AJAX
  // on success, turn "next page" button to green
  turnButtonGreen();
  // return true or false...
}

function turnButtonGreen() {
  // set "next page" button class to make it green and enable it
}

function buttonIsGreen() {
  // return true if button is green.
}
```

In this example, you can see that I am "chaining" events; a practice which I think is a bad idea. ie, `addRecord()`, on success, runs `areAmountsEqual()`, which on success runs `turnButtonGreen()`...  where does it stop?

It seems it would be much better to have observers watching for a record change, or for amounts being equal-- but I just don't know how to do that in javascript.

With that in mind, my question is: How do you make an observer that watches for two separate events to be true:

1. `enter` key is pressed while in the `amount` field, AND
2. amounts in database become equal to the `batch` amount

If I can understand that, then the other observers should be child's play.